# What are the major differences between Dart and Java 8 / C#?

Tags: c#, java, javascript, dart, java-8

I am a Java developer and recently I started reading about the language Dart and the more I read, the more I have a feeling it's very similar to Java 8.

For this question not to sound completely out-of-this-world, I'll try to list similarities between Dart and Java 8 which make them almost twins.

- ["Loves structure and static type checking. In Dart every object has a static shape."](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/3/20/dart-is-it-the-future-of-the-web.html)
- "Class based and object oriented"
- [Generics](http://blog.sethladd.com/2012/01/generics-in-dart-or-why-javascript.html).
- ["Lexical `this`. Unlike JavaScript when you use `this` you know what it is referring to"](http://highscalability.com/blog/2013/3/20/dart-is-it-the-future-of-the-web.html)
- "Hole free arrays."
- [Has maps.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14930950/what-are-the-differences-between-the-different-map-implementations-in-dart)
- "Has both integers and doubles."
- [Has sockets and file IO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515398/will-dart-be-used-serverside/9516060#9516060).
- [Has isolates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957253/difference-between-dart-isolate-and-thread-java-c).
- [Has a package manager](http://pub.dartlang.org/).
- [Performance comparable to Java.](http://bonovox.be/blog/dart-vs-java-the-deltablue-benchmark/)
- Historical: JS was introduced as a simplified dynamic version of Java/C++ which could be run in browsers. Dart is something very opposite to this - it's more static and has more features.

First I thought that may be currying, but [currying is there in Java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14750362/1851024).

So other than syntax, what are the major differences between Dart and Java 8 / C#?

**UPDATE**

This answer from @SethLadd who is one of the developers of Dart: [Does Dart have any useful features for web programmers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/164304/104086) enlists all the major features of the Dart language, so it might leave no trouble comparing these languages.

Comment: And this is not too broad:  [What are major differences between C# and Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295224/what-are-major-differences-between-c-sharp-and-java)

Comment: That question probably should have a "Only kept for historical reasons - not a good question" notice attached.  It is too broad as well.

Comment: Updated the question, feel free to close it or move to Programmers Stackexchange.